# Any tool to assist in building REST controller specs?

Tags: ruby, testing, rest, rspec, controller

I'm sick of writing out the same controller specs each time I make a new controller. I know I can use the scaffold generator, but there are enough little things I have to change that it usually doesn't save me much time.

Are there any projects/tools out there that provide some sort of base set of specs and/or a DSL to make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

I've never found that any two REST controllers I wanted to write had similar enough interfaces that the tests were at all similar (and generally, I recommend Cucumber, not controller specs).

Something like inherited_resources or Rails 3's `respond_with` is very useful for *writing* the controllers, but I'm not sure about the tests.

Comment: Interesting… coming at the problem from the other side. I think I would still want to write a full test suite though, unless I was using the absolute vanilla inherited_resources config.

Comment: What do you mean by coming at the problem from the other side? Do you mean that I'm putting the DRY stuff in the implementation instead of the tests? If so, that's the way it should be...

Answer (score 0):

I use the [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) gem.

Comment: a valid point. I think my tired brain substituted something else for "spec" and I thought you were asking for an easier way to setup the controller itself, not the spec to test it. Apologies.